# I’m intending doing the UK C2C and wondered what would be the most suitable bike to buy?

Tags: touring, product-rec, uk

Bike choice £1000 Coast to coast ride in the UK.

Been riding a Ridgeback Voyage but too heavy.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: The only suitable bike to buy is the one you personally find comfortable, and one that you can actually purchase in these days of weird C19-affected supply lines.  Everything else is irrelevant.

Comment: What I can find about the Ridgeback Voyage suggests that it would be ideal for this kind of ride, unless you're trying to set some sort of speed record.

Comment: @DanielRHicks's right.  My road bike is a similar tourer (Genesis Tour de Fer), and assuming you mean [this route](https://ridewithgps.com/routes/537682) or one like It, it would be well suited, especially if you had to carry overnight gear.  Unladen I'd do it it in a day on mine but it's a bit much climbing with even my lightweight camping setup for one day; you don't give any idea of your intended timescale or load.

Comment: The bike does look heavy even from its look. Throw away the fenders and the rack. Get pickepacking bags.

Comment: @VladimirF you've clearly not ridden much  in the UK:  the roads are as often as not wet here, and in rural areas plenty of the mud on the roads came out of the back end of cattle.  By all means lose the rack (I put mine on for heavy touring, off for other stuff) but the mudguards don't weigh much and it's not like it's  alpine riding with multi-hour ascents

Comment: @ChrisH I lived in Southampton for two years. Not once did I get really  wet on my bike. I did hundreds of sunny miles on the road. Do not make UK wetter than it really is.

Comment: @ChrisH And when one does get to ride in the mud off-road, then every cm of the mud clearance is worth it. The fenders will get clogged. People either use wide plastic ass-savers (and the front equivalent that I do not know the name of) or nothing in the long-distance MTB races I am aware of.

Comment: @VladimirF Southampton is a bit drier than where I live, or Cumbria, but OK. On the mtb I agree with you, but this is basically a road ride with optional gravel sections. Even those would be ok on my 32mm slicks which don't pick up mud like knobbly tyres.

Answer (score 4):

I am not from the UK, but the acronym appears to refer to the Coast to Coast walk or ride event. (NB: please do be more specific on acronyms, as not everyone may be familiar with them, and you aren't guaranteed that someone is going to be willing and able to Google them.) [One version](https://cycleactive.com/index.php/cycling-holidays/classic-coast-to-coast-c2c) of the ride appears to cover 137 miles, or 220.5 km, in 3 days.

Another thing to note about this forum is that we aren't a traditional free-form discussion forum. For one, as the FAQ says, questions seeking specific product recommendations are considered off topic for the reasons Daniel stated in a comment.

I feel that it is possible to answer the question in very general terms without naming specific products. I would normally suggest not a mountain bike, if possible. You could certainly complete the ride, but the knobby tires and suspension would consume some energy you don't need to spend - you could ameliorate this by changing to slicks and locking out the suspension if able.

The answer is complicated by the fact that you already appear to have a touring bicycle. If Google is a good guide, you have a [steel touring bike](https://www.ridgeback.co.uk/ridgeback-voyage-varrb2151) whose MSRP was about £1k. This is the type of bike I would have recommended if you were starting from scratch and you wanted to do a lot of this type of riding.  The current model year appears to have triple chainrings and provisions for rack mounts. You indicated that this is too heavy. Unfortunately, I have a feeling that you aren't likely to do much better for the price range you indicated. I don't know how much elevation gain you face, but for the most part, changing to a lighter bike doesn't make much of a difference in performance, unless you're going up an extended and steep climb and/or you drop 5 lbs or more from the bike. Also, a lighter road frame will severely limit your ability to carry luggage.

Without meaning to gaslight you about the bike feeling too heavy, do be aware that you can use that smallest ring to get up steep hills. If you can't shift because the derailer is out of adjustment, a bike store will be able to help you get it in adjustment, and they can refresh you on how to change gears.

Comment: Concur - a tuneup and some fresh tyres would be a good basic plan.  Possibly replace the bartape for that new-bike feel as well.

Comment: There are lots of variations of coast-to-coast rides in the UK. You can go across Devon, across the Pennines in several different ways, across Scotland. OP needs to be more specific.

Comment: You can book a package holiday through Skeddadle for C2C and hire a bike cheaper than buying a bike and then having the hassle of transporting a bike up there.

Comment: I reckon you could actually save that more than 5lb off that within the price range - something like  the Trek Domane AL3 at £995 is about 10.5kg to the Voyager's 13.7kg.  That's nearly 7lb difference.  I still wouldn't do it though.  The climb on [one version](https://ridewithgps.com/routes/537682) of C2C is about 3800m in 220km, so reasonably hilly.  The longest climb is around 500m in 15km, but even that isn't continuous.  An unbroken 1300m in 30km was very slow indeed on a comparable bike, but doable